# Facebook - post to page wall when user is not logged in (via FbGraph)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cron, fb-graph

I use `FbGraph` gem and this part of code:

```
page = FbGraph::Page.new(ID_OF_MY_PAGE)
feed = page.feed!(
  :access_token => access_token,
  :subject => 'testing',
  :message => 'Hey, I\'m testing you!'
)
```

It's working only if I (as the owner of the page) am logged in. I would need to run this task with CRON. Is there any way to set up the tokens for posting statuses if I wouldn't need to be logged in?

Comment: Unfortunately, **offline_access** scope was removed. See https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Ok. So the second way - I need to get the `access_token`. Could you help me, please, how to get it for currently logged-in user? I know that the `access_token` is generated, when a user is logged out, but I don't know, how to get it from user and use it in the snippet.